# SDWebImage 2.7.4 version - allow http caching

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

Latest version of SDWebImage allows app to override its rigorous caching mechanism and honor HTTP Cache headers with this flag - SDWebImageRefreshCached but its not available in older versions. Is it possible to do the same with older version 2.7.4?

Thx

Comment: and why would you like it in a older version ?

Comment: the new version doesnt work well for me.. the images dont load sporadically.. the same issues described (here) [github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/138] and (here) [https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/363] which didnt seem to have really resolved but the old version that got downloaded with MWPhotoBrowser works just fine.

Comment: I didnt ask any one to port the code. I just asked if it was done in older versions and if yes how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer to the question but it did solve my problem. Looking more into the code I found that the images are not cached for ever. The api uses maxCacheAge to expire the cache and clear the images and this is set to 1 week by default. In 2.7.4 this value can not be modified but I believe it can be in later versions. in case this helps someone.

```
static NSInteger cacheMaxCacheAge = 60*60*24*7; // 1 week
```